# Android ScrollView Oculta Elementos

Tags: java, android, xml

Tengo un XML el cual le agrege un `ScrollView` por si algun dispositivo tenia pantalla mas pequeña  , el problema viene en que al al hacerle foco al ultimo elemento de mis `edittexts` el boton de aceptar el cual siempre esta en `BOTTOM true` me tapa mi caja donde estoy escribiendo , dejo mi xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="330dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:itemIconTint="#000000" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_activation_step1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">
        <include layout="@layout/actionbar_toolbar"/>
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/foto_galleryy"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:background="@mipmap/nopicture" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/badge"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/foto_galleryy"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/foto_galleryy"
                    android:background="@mipmap/cameraxxxhdpi"
                    android:onClick="LoadImage" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/NombrePersona"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/foto_galleryy"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/T18" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/strtxtCellPhone"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/NombrePersona"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:enabled="false"
                    android:text="@string/strtxtCellPhone"
                    android:textColor="@color/BotonsHome"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/T16" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/strTxtCellPhoneInformations"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/strtxtCellPhone"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/HintHomeMonto"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/T14" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/strtxtNroCuenta"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/strTxtCellPhoneInformations"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:enabled="false"
                    android:text="@string/NroCuenta"
                    android:textColor="@color/BotonsHome"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/T16" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/strTxtNroCuenta"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/strtxtNroCuenta"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/HintHomeMonto"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/T14" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/strtxtEntidadFinanciera"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/strTxtNroCuenta"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:enabled="false"
                    android:text="@string/strTxtEntidadFinanciera"
                    android:textColor="@color/BotonsHome"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/T16" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/strEditEntidadFinanciera"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/strtxtEntidadFinanciera"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/HintHomeMonto"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/T14" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/strtxtEmail"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/strEditEntidadFinanciera"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/strtxtemail"
                    android:textColor="@color/BotonsHome"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/T16" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/strEditEmail"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/strtxtEmail"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:maxLength="35"
                    android:textColor="@color/HintHomeMonto"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/T14" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/iconodeaceptar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/redondoazul"
                    android:onClick="guardarDatos"
                    android:text="Continuar"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

La primer Imagen muestra el formulario entero

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando selecciono el ultimo `EditText`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el scroll hace que el boton sobrepase a la caja dejando la caja oculta no entiendo porque pasa esto desde ya gracias!

Comment: intenta poner el valor de tu botón en vez de `layout_alignParentBottom= false` quitalo y haz lo siguiente `android:layout_below="@+id/strEditEmail` así el boton estará posicionado debajo del edit text y no alineado al bottom de tu Layout Padre es por eso que el boton salta al hacer la ultima seleccion al edittext

Comment: la otra que sería es sacar el boton fuera del scroll view y alinear el scroll al margen del boton

Comment: @MiguelOsorio utilize lo que me dijiste y anda perfecto si quieres ponlo como respesta para marcarte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta poner el valor de tu botón en vez de `layout_alignParentBottom= false` quitalo y haz lo siguiente `android:layout_below="@+id/strEditEmail` así el boton estará posicionado debajo del edit text y no alineado al bottom de tu Layout Padre es por eso que el boton salta al hacer la ultima seleccion al edittext.

La otra que sería es sacar el boton fuera del scroll view y alinear el scroll al margen del botón

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de definir en el botón:

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

define que este botón se encuentre abajo del EditText con id `strEditEmail`,

```
 android:layout_below="@+id/strEditEmail"
```

de esta forma el botón siempre aparecería abajo:

```
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/iconodeaceptar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"

                android:layout_below="@+id/strEditEmail"

                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/redondoazul"
                android:onClick="guardarDatos"
                android:text="Continuar"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

Comment: el problema es que yo quiero que este boton siempre este abajo del todo de la pantalla , por ejemplo si tuviera solo 2 cajas , no quiero que el boton este pegado abajo de la caja quiero que este abajo?

Comment: Siempre estaria abajo incluso del teclado virtual, ya lo probaste Bruno

Comment: ah lo que voy es que este abajo siempre de la pantalla , este casi como tiene tantos edittext quedaria como abajo , pero no siempre es el caso , de igual forma si lo pobre y anda!